# How to update a document of an elasticsearch in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I used the following query to update a document.

```
$es_client.update index: 'users', type: 'actions' ,body: { user_id: user, product_id: [recent_positive] }
```

But it didn't work. Where am I supposed to mention the id value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` field is to be sent as one of the params to `update` method. Another thing to note, to update a doc, you must use `doc` field inside `body`
like this:

```
$es_client.update index: 'users', id: 1, type: 'actions', body: { doc: {user_id: user, product_id: [recent_positive] } }
```

Refer: [esclient-ruby-update-method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch%2FAPI%2FActions:update)